# Integral Inequality Product

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose

1. $a<b<c$
2. $f\ge 0$ on $[a,b]$
3. $f\le 0$ on $[b,c]$
4. $g \ge 0$ on $[a,c]$
5. $\int_a^b f = -\int_b^c f$
6. $\int_a^b g \ge \int_b^c g$,

Prove or disprove $\int_a^c fg \ge 0$. Are there generalizations? Do I need all the assumptions?

Comment: Disproving that is very easy though, let $f=0$ for all values then all of the conditions are satisfied and the integral over $fg$ is zero. Are you sure it's not $>$ rather than $\geq$ and vice-versa in conditions 2 and 3?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Switching to strict inequality actually doesn't help: qualitatively, we can think of "choosing" intervals for $g$ to have its largest values in $[b,c]$ over regions where $f$ reaches high magnitudes, in essence giving them more weight. (I have worked out a specific example to make sure this goes through properly but this description should get the idea across)

Comment: @SuzuHirose Ah yes the zero case does fail. I have edited to be non-strict.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Care to post your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x+1$ on the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$, serve as a sufficient counter-example. I have formulated a new question, this time with the property of increasing.

[Integration of a product of an increasing function with an integral zero function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472824/integration-of-a-product-of-an-increasing-function-with-an-integral-zero-functio)