# Integration of a product of an increasing function with an integral zero function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Suppose:

1. $a<b<c$
2. $\int_a^c f=0$
3. $f\le 0$ on $[a,b]$, $f\ge 0$ on $[b,c]$
4. $g$ is a positive increasing function on $[a,c]$

Must it be the case that $\int_a^c fg \ge 0$?

---

Not sure why the question is being flagged, I thought the question was very clearly stated. This is a website to ask math questions on. I had a math question. A community member had an answer, and graciously helped. I am grateful we have such a platform to communicate on. It is unclear what the issue is. Do the flaggers feel it is too trivial for them, by what standard? What is unclear to one person can be made clear by another's help. Discouraging posts because they seem "easy" to some, seems clearly against the purpose of this site. I don't think people should be discouraged from asking questions.

---

Context. In researching kernel transformation operators that preserve hyperbolicity, I came across a very large double integral, which I needed to be positive. I was unsure the properties I would need to guarantee such result and wasn't even sure which properties would be helpful. After several days I managed to get it in the form $\int fg$. After several more days, I finally was able to prove that $f$ (being a double series consine transform) was positive and increasing. Likewise $g$ with appropriate coefficient turned out to $\int g = 0$ has a single root, and was negative to the left of that root and positive to the right. I wasn't sure if those were sufficient, as usual I popped over to math.stackexchange.com to do some inquiry and couldn't find the exact question of interest. I was fairly confident that the proposition was true and was sure someone could provide a clever proof, that I couldn't see (maybe too tired). Again, I am completely unsure why this added information would increase the quality of the question. What exactly is the concern?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I intended that $g$ be positive increasing on the whole interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $g$ is a positive increasing function on $[a,b]$

This condition is not enough to guarantee the proposition holds since we know nothing of $g$'s behavior from $(b,c]$. One counterexample is
$$
f(x) = \sin(-x) , \quad g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - \left(\frac{x}{\pi}-1\right)^2  &0\le x \le \pi \\ 1-((x-\pi)^{100}& \pi < x \le 2\pi\end{cases}, \quad a =0, b=\pi, c=2\pi
$$
Since $g$ bolts to negative numbers for values greater than $\pi$, the integral $\int_a^c fg$ is very much negative.

---

If we change point four to

> $g$ is an increasing function on $[a,c]$

then the proposition does hold true.

***Proof:***
On $[a,b]$, since $g$ is increasing and $f \le 0$ we have
\begin{align}
 g(x) \le g(b) &\implies f(x)g(x) \ge f(x)g(b)\implies \int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \ge g(b)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
And analogously, since on $[b,c]$ we have $f \ge 0$
\begin{align}
g(b) \le g(x)  &\implies f(x)g(b)\le f(x)g(x) \implies  \int_{b}^{c}f(x)g(x)\, \mathrm{d}x  \ge g(b)\int_{b}^{c}f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
Lastly, notice that
$$
\int_a^c f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x =0 \implies \int_a^b f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = - \int_b^c f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x
$$
So combining everything we get
\begin{align}
\int_a^c f(x) g(x)\, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_a^b f(x) g(x)\, \mathrm{d}x  + \int_b^c f(x) g(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& \ge g(b)\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x +g(b) \int_{b}^c f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = g(b)\left[- \int_{b}^c f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x  +  \int_{b}^c f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x  \right]\\
& =0
\end{align}
*Q.E.D.*

Comment: Oh my bad, I mistyped. The intention was for $g$ to be positive and increasing on [a,c].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I lost in my work, I just couldn't see it. In fact $g$ positive wasn't even relevant. Thanks.

Comment: I think the  question is missing context.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What improvement were you looking for exactly? I still don't know why the question was flagged. The added "context" paragraph seems completely out of context to the question and does nothing to help with an answer.

Comment: That paragraph was added by you. Are you saying that, in your own opinion, that paragraph adds no context to the question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Well, yes, that is correct. That paragraph does very little to supplement the context of the main question. It basically does nothing more than indicate I am a math researcher. I personally don't think the validity of questions should be determined by the status or knowledge of the OP. I shouldn't have to give my credentials in order to have conversations with other mathematicians. Even if the question is trivial.

Comment: But one of our rules is that questions must have a context. Your question is about conditions under which $\int_a^cfg\geqslant0$ and you told us in which context you got it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could I have simply stated "I came across this particular integral problem I belive to be true while doing some research, any help would be appreciated."? I have done minor pleasantries like that in the past and have also been flagged adding too much unnecessary information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137153/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-bobby-ocean).